# jQuery Locationpicker set multiple locations

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, location

I had a problem yesterday with a [location picker](http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/) which has been solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40369884/3972773)

This works for two out of three cases but for the last one I can not figure out how to get it to work.

To summarize my previous question: I have a locationpicker from which I need to extract certain values after initializing. To achieve this I use this piece of code, the function setLocation is my own and works as intended.

```
$("#locationpicker").locationpicker({
    location: {latitude: 10, longitude: 10},
    radius: 10,
    inputBinding:
    {
        latitudeInput: $("#locationpicker_lat"),
        longitudeInput: $("#locationpicker_lon"),
        radiusInput: $("#locationpicker_radius"),
        locationNameInput: $("#locationpicker_address")
    },
    oninitialized: function(component){
        setLocation("end");

        //1. attempt
        component.location = {latitude: 20, longitude: 20};

        //2. attempt
        var mapContext = component.locationpicker("map");
        mapContext.map.radius = 500;

        //3. attempt - I work, but then setLocation below not any more
        component.locationpicker("location", {latitude:10.0, longitude:10.0});

        setLocation("start");
    },
    enableAutocomplete: true
});
```

I call the function `setLocation()` twice but need to change the location between them. I could not find in the documentation of the locationpicker how to set a new location (latitude, longitude, radius) and various attempts have failed as well. Two of them can be viewed in the code.

I thought about using the origianl [google maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=de) but have no idea whether this works and how exactly to use it.

I hope I described my problem detailed enough and if any piece of information is missing I will provide it immediatly.

**UPDATE 1**

I am able to change the location to a value I need to, but then the extraction for the second set of variables is not correct any more.

This inside the oninitilaized function works

```
component.locationpicker("location", {latitude:10.0, longitude:10.0});
```

Since the function `setLocation` does not work at the current state i post it here as well:

```
function setLocation(option)
{
    var lat = $("#locationpicker_lat").val();
    var lon = $("#locationpicker_lon").val();
    var add = $("#locationpicker_address").val();
    var rad = $("#locationpicker_radius").val();

    if(rad == "")
    {
        rad = 0;
    }

    if(option == "start")
    {
        document.getElementById("start_location_lat").value = lat;
        document.getElementById("start_location_lon").value = lon;
        document.getElementById("start_location_rad").value = rad;

        document.getElementById("display_start_location").innerHTML = add + ", Radius: " + rad + "m";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("end_location_lat").value = lat;
        document.getElementById("end_location_lon").value = lon;
        document.getElementById("end_location_rad").value = rad;

        document.getElementById("display_end_location").innerHTML = add + ", Radius: " + rad + "m";
    }
}
```

Comment: is that possible to add multiple markers using locationpicker.jquery.js?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a separate listener for the start and end location. This way, you can debug your app more easier and makes it easier to understand.

Sample Code

```
<div id="start" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
<div id="end" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script>

function setLocation_start(){
//your code for start
$('#start').locationpicker();
}

function setLocation_end(){
//your code for end
$('#end').locationpicker();
}

</script>
```

The image is an example of a separate listener for start and end location.

[image]

Comment: The problem is no longer relevant but I appreciate your effort. Thank you anyway.